# How do i make a cordova plugin into an npm package

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova plugin and I need to make an npm package how do I do this.

Are there any tutorials etc.

Many Thanks,

Laurence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to contribute a package to npm for public usage you can follow this [instruction](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-unscoped-public-packages). If you want to have a private package it's a paid option.

If you already set up a GitHub repository with your plugin correctly you can use it without adding it to the npm. Just use your repository URL when you installing it:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console.git
```

Comment: Hi I know about the Cordova plugin add command. The reason I want to make a Cordova plugin available on npm as I want to use it with a Softwares build service and they only take npm packages. SO somehow I have to make the Cordova plugin an npm package how do i do this?

Comment: @L.bedford you can check the instruction linked in the first sentence of my answer. Cordova plugins can be added to npm the same way as other npm packages.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help! I have successfully managed to port the Cordova plugin to an npm package!

Comment: @L.bedford nice to hear it!